# Angular CLI & Material table

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня не происходит отображение данных в Material table. Никак не могу понять. Причем данные есть, мало того, количество строк соответствует реальному количеству данных, однако таблица просто пустая.

[image: Пустая таблица]

**device.model.ts**

```
export class DeviceModel {
  private _id: number;
  private _device: string;
  private _status: string;
  private _lastUpdate: Date;

  contructor(id?: number,
             device?: string,
             status?: string,
             lastUpdate?: Date) {
    this._id = id;
    this._device = device;
    this._status = status;
    this._lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
  }

  get id(): number {
    return this._id;
  }

  set id(value: number) {
    this._id = value;
  }

  get device(): string {
    return this._device;
  }

  set device(value: string) {
    this._device = value;
  }

  get status(): string {
    return this._status;
  }

  set status(value: string) {
    this._status = value;
  }

  get lastUpdate(): Date {
    return this._lastUpdate;
  }

  set lastUpdate(value: Date) {
    this._lastUpdate = value;
  }
}
```

**device.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable, of} from "rxjs";
import {AppConfig} from "../../../config/app.config";
import {DeviceModel} from "./device.model";
import {LoggerService} from "../../../core/shared/logger.service";
import {catchError, tap} from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeviceService {

  private readonly deviceUrl: string;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.deviceUrl = AppConfig.endpoints.device;
  }

  private static handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      LoggerService.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      if (error.status >= 500) {
        throw error;
      }

      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  public getAllDevices(): Observable<DeviceModel[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<DeviceModel[]>(this.deviceUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => LoggerService.log(`fetched devices`)),
        catchError(DeviceService.handleError('getDevices', []))
      );
  }
}
```

**device-list.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DeviceModel} from "../../shared/device.model";
import {DeviceService} from "../../shared/device.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-device',
  templateUrl: './device-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device-list.component.scss']
})

export class DeviceListComponent implements OnInit {

  devices: DeviceModel[];
  displayedColumns: ['id', 'device', 'state', 'lastUpdate'];

  constructor(private deviceService: DeviceService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.deviceService.getAllDevices().subscribe((devices: DeviceModel[]) => {
      this.devices = devices
    });
    console.log(this.devices);
  }

}
```

**device-list.components.html**

```
  <!-- Table container-->
  <div class="table-container">
    <mat-table #deviceTable [dataSource]="devices">

      <!-- Id Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let device">{{device.id}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Device Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="device">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Device </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let device">{{device.device}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Status Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> State </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let device">{{device.state}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Lst update Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="lastUpdate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last update </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let device">{{device.lastUpdate}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

    </mat-table>
  </div>
  <!-- Table container-->
```

Причем если вывести в обычной html-таблице - данные есть.

[image: Html-table]

```
<div>
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>DeviceModel</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Last update</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let device of devices">
        <td>{{device.id}}</td>
        <td>{{device.device}}</td>
        <td>{{device.status}}</td>
        <td>{{device.lastUpdate}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Я конечно склоняюсь к тому, что у меня как-то неправильно происходит map данных в DeviceModel в DeviceService. Но я никак не могу понять, что же не так. Так же прикладываю содержание логов в консоли.

[image: Chrome log]

В целом там уже видно, что массив devices у меня undefined.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне можно исправить эту ситуацию?

Всем очень благодарен заранее.

P.S.: Я занимаюсь angular совсем-совсем недавно, буквально несколько дней, поэтому прошу прощения, если я могу порой не замечать вполне очевидные вещи.

Я внес корректировки согласно [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/876220/308022).

Спасибо, это помогло, теперь работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых `data-bound` свойство `dataSource` ожидает инстанс `MatTableDataSource`, а не обычный массив:

```
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

@Component({ ... })
export class DeviceListComponent {
    public devices = new MatTableDataSource<DeviceModel>([]);

    constructor(private deviceService: DeviceService) {
        this.deviceService.getDevices().toPromise().then((devices: DeviceModel[]) => {
            this.devices.data = devices;
        });
    }
}
```

Во-вторых не нужно создавать такие комплексные модели, типа `DeviceModel` с приватными свойствами, геттерами и сеттерами, в данном случае простого контракта достаточно:

```
export interface Device {
    id: number;
    device: string;
    status: string;
    lastUpdate: Date;
}
```

К тому же вы неправильно инициализируете `displayedColumns`, здесь вы объявляете просто тип:

```
displayedColumns: ['id', 'device', 'state', 'lastUpdate'];
```

А нужно провести инициализацию:

```
displayedColumns: ReadonlyArray<string> = ['id', 'device', 'state', 'lastUpdate'];
```

Преобразовываем `lastUpdate` типа `number` в `Date`:

```
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeviceService {
    private readonly deviceUrl: string = AppConfig.endpoints.device;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    public getAllDevices(): Promise<DeviceModel[]> {
        return this.http.get<DeviceModel[]>(this.deviceUrl).pipe(
            tap(() => LoggerService.log(`fetched devices`))
        ).toPromise().then((devices: DeviceModel[]) => {
            devices.forEach((device: DeviceModel) => {
                device.lastUpdate = new Date(device.lastUpdate);
            });

            return devices;
        });
    }
}
```

В компоненте просто вызываем данный метод в конструкторе:

```
constructor(private deviceService: DeviceService) {
    this.deviceService.getAllDevices().then((devices: DeviceModel[]) => {
        this.dataSource.data = devices;
    });
}
```

Также в шаблоне вы теперь можете использовать [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: Попробовал так сделать, но теперь выходит новая ошибка: 
`Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`
Ошибка происходит в месте:
`<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>`
Вообще, первый рак вижу такой вариант решения, я изначально пробовал как показано в [примерах material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples), там используются обычные массивы.

Comment: @titaniche, обновил

Comment: Еще хотел маленький вопросик уточнить.
Сервис у меня возвращает результат lastUpdate как number. Можно-ли как-то сразу его мапить в Date? В смысле, прямо в сервисе, когда происходит `httpClient.get()`, чтобы отдельно потом внутри компонента не делать этого.

Comment: @titaniche, да, сейчас добавлю

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду иметь ввиду.